How to Reduce Layout Service Calls in Headless Sitecore with Rendering SDK via Caching
I’m working on a Sitecore Headless project using the .NET Rendering SDK.
Every time the Rendering Host makes a request for data, it calls the Layout Service on the CD server.
To improve performance and reduce the number of these calls, I’m looking to implement caching on the Rendering Host or Layout Service.
Are there Sitecore-recommended solutions to optimize Layout Service calls in a headless setup? I've already tried the Sitecore output caching but that still hits CD every time.

As a question, have you looked at CDN tech or possibly static generation for your caching? Something like Vercel will give you the option to only really hit the LayoutService when you are doing the rebuild of the page. If you have to run SSR, that won't work, but might be something worth looking into?
